# Store several shapes under a variable

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

New to VBA, looking for assistance.

Im selecting several shapes, performing modifications then I want to select the same shapes again. Im looking to store the originally selected shapes under a variable.

```
Sub TEst()
   ' Call format_select
    'Call Resize_selected_row_Click
Dim S As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
Set S = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Selection)
For Each shp In Selection
    shp.Select
    'Call format_select
Next shp

S.Select
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe grouping the selected shapes (`.Group`), and looping through the `groupItems` could work

Comment: [`ShapeRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shaperange) object?

Comment: Can you please tell us what information you are looking to store from each shape? If you can tell us what shape you selected and what you want to store that will probably be possible.

Comment: my goal is, prior to ending the sub, to re-select all the shapes that were selected at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `Dictionary` in this type of situations. But you can have the same result using `array`, but I dislike the worry with array size.

By the way I use selection `strGroup = Selection.Name` here, I dont recomend using `Selection` can give you some problens in future.

```
Sub LoopThroughGroupShapes()

    Dim shpGroup As Shape
    Dim strGroup As String
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    Dim vDicShapes As Object
    
    Set vDicShapes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    strGroup = Selection.Name
    
    Set shpGroup = ActiveSheet.Shapes(strGroup)
    
    For Each shp In shpGroup.GroupItems
        'Debug.Print shp.Name
        vDicShapes.Add shp.Name, shp
    Next shp
    
    'Debug.Print vDicShapes.Count, vDicShapes("Rectangle 6").Name
    
End Sub
```

With this you can go and call by name of shape to access then with: `vDicShapes("Rectangle 6").name` and manipulate direct from the dictionary. You can copy the dictionary remove from dictionary a few shapes and execute some tasks with so.

I will leave a site with more information about Dictionary in VBA:
https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/